# On clicking the multiple checkboxes how do I store listview row items in a string format (list<string> or any other logical datastructure)

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, gridview

Here is what I am trying to achieve.I have built a view using ListView and have bounded the ItemSource of the ListView with the XML file so that it displays xml content as listview Items.Also I have provided GridView Column in the ListView to put checkboxes and textboxes for  each xml content.

Here is the xaml code for this.

```
    <Window.Resources>
            <!--XML Data Source-->
            <XmlDataProvider x:Key="InstrumentList" Source="Instrumentlist.xml"/>
        </Window.Resources>
        <Grid>

            <ListView Height="153" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                  Name="listView1" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                  Width="503"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource InstrumentList}, XPath=instrument/instruments}">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridView.Columns>
                            <GridViewColumn x:Name="g1" >
                                <GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate >
                                        <CheckBox x:Name="checkall" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <CheckBox IsChecked="False"/>

                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn  Header="Instrref" />
                            <GridViewColumn Width="120" Header="OrderLimit">
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBox Name="txt_OrderLimit" Width="100"/>

                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Width="120" Header="ValueLimit">
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBox Name="txt_ValueLimit" Width="100"/>

                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>

                        </GridView.Columns>


                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
            <Button x:Name="button" Content="Submit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,174,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="194" Click="button_Click"/>
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

Above we have checkbox and two textboxes inside GridView datatemplate.When I do a multiple checkes on the checkboxes i want to retrieve xml data content along with textbox contents to get stored in some useful resource so that I can access it later.

The XML file content:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <instrument>

      <instruments>
      <instrument_reference>NIFTY12SEP8700CE</instrument_reference>
      </instruments>
      <instruments>
      <instrument_reference>NIFTY12SEP8600CE</instrument_reference>
      </instruments>
      <instruments>
      <instrument_reference>NIFTY12SEP8900CE</instrument_reference>
      </instruments>
      <instruments>
        <instrument_reference>NIFTY12SEP9000CE</instrument_reference>
      </instruments>
      <instruments>
        <instrument_reference>NIFTY12SEP9100CE</instrument_reference>
      </instruments>
      <instruments>
        <instrument_reference>NIFTY12SEP9200CE</instrument_reference>
      </instruments>
    </instrument>
```

As you can see how the view is looking in the provided screenshot.I wanted to do a multiple checks on the checkboxes and provide input to the textboxes so that when i click submit button,on buttonn click event I should able to get the -INSTRUMENT REF,TEXTBOX-ORDERLIMIT,TEXTBOX-VALUELIMIT values stored in datatable,list or whatever convenient resource to access for later use.

Please help how can i access those element values.

Answer (score 1):

Start by putting an Event Handler on your `checkAll`, setting that up accordingly, and giving your `GridView` a name.  Something like:

### XAML

```
<GridView x:Name="gvMyGridView">
    //EVERYTHING ELSE
</GridView>
```

### C#

```
private void checkAll_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (checkAll.IsChecked == true)
    {
        foreach (GridViewColumn gvc in gvMyGridView.Children)
        {
            foreach (CellTemplate ct in gvc)
            {
                foreach (Checkbox cb in ct)
                {
                    cb.IsChecked = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can kind of rinse and repeat that to get your string values from the text boxes and assign them to a `List<string>` like:

```
private void button_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    List<string> lstContent = new List<string>();
    foreach (GridViewColumn gvc in gvMyGridView.Children)
    {
        foreach (CellTemplate ct in gvc)
        {
            foreach (Checkbox cb in ct)
            {
                if (cb.IsChecked == true)
                    lstContent.Add(/*Corresponding Text Box*/.Content.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.  Let me know what happens, and if you need more help, I'll do what I can

Comment: :This isn't working.Since this is a WPF cntrls hr what errors I am getting while following this approach. 1.Inside private void checkAll_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
//** checkAll is not accessible since it is inside DataTemplate.I know this as I tried to access it in fairly simple manner but failed to do so**// .Secondly "gvMyGridView.Children"  giving error -'GridView dsnt contain definition for  'GridView' does not contain a definition for 'Children' and no extension method 'Children' accepting a first arg of type and subsequently CellTemplate couldnt be fnd. @Geoff